# RHEL6.8 service command not working

Tags: rhel, services

I have two systems both running RHEL 6.8, each was cloned from the same template but the salt401 system is having a strange issue, the service command does not return anything. I have tried a few different service commands but no results.

I have tested as different users using sudo but same result. I compared the .bash_profiles but they are the same.

For this example I do know that the ssh daemon is running since I can ssh to the system.

```
[root@salt401 ~]# service sshd status
[root@salt401 ~]#

[root@salt404 ~]# service sshd status
openssh-daemon (pid  2260) is running...
[root@salt404 ~]#
```

How do I get the service command to output results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried reinstalling the package containing /bin/env?

```
# yum reinstall `rpm -qf /bin/env`
```

You can also check [redhat's customer portal](https://access.redhat.com/solutions/330443?tour=6).

In addition to reinstalling `/bin/env`, initscripts also needs to be reinstalled.

```
# yum reinstall initscripts
```

Comment: Package has been reinstalled but same issue.

Comment: @SpruceTips as mentioned in the above link, if you run "/etc/init.d/sshd status" do you get any output?

Comment: this command works 
`[root@dnvusalt401 ~]# /etc/init.d/sshd status`
`openssh-daemon (pid  1928) is running...`